# property of 'QuadContourSet' object has no setter error after update matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I wrote and ran a cod to plot a netcdf file. after upgrade pip and Libraries used , I got an error:property of 'QuadContourSet' object has no setter.
I would be grateful if someone could help me to fix this error
this is my code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker 
from matplotlib.axis import Axis
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,9), constrained_layout=True ) 
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0 )
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
nc1 = NetCDFFile('C:/Users/Hadish/Desktop/project/shLa1850.nc')
lat = nc1.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc1.variables['lon'][:]
sh = nc1.variables['shum'][:]
nc2 = NetCDFFile('C:/Users/Hadish/Desktop/project/omegaLa1500.nc')
lat = nc2.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc2.variables['lon'][:]
omega = nc2.variables['omega'][:]*1000
map=Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlon=0.,llcrnrlat=10.,urcrnrlon=80.,urcrnrlat=45.
,resolution='i' ,suppress_ticks=False)  
lat_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(15.0),int(45.0),5)
lon_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(40.0),int(70.0),5)
lon_ticks_proj, _=map(lon_ticks, np.zeros(len(lon_ticks)))
_, lat_ticks_proj=map(np.zeros(len(lat_ticks)), lat_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(lon_ticks_proj)
ax.set_yticks(lat_ticks_proj)
plt.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False , axis='both',which='major')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawlsmask(land_color='Linen', ocean_color='#CCFFFF')
map.drawcounties() 
map.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10 , dashes=(0,1),
fontweight='bold' ,fontstyle='oblique')
map.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10, dashes=(0,1) , 
fontweight='bold',  fontstyle='oblique')
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon-180,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
clevs1 = np.arange(-6,6,1)
plt.title('SH')
cs1 = map.contourf(x,y,sh[0,:,:],clevs1,cmap='RdBu')
cb = map.colorbar(cs1,"bottom", size="4%", pad="5%")
cb.set_label('SH*10000')
clevs2 = np.arange(-10,10,2)
cs2 = map.contour(x,y,omega[0,:,:],clevs2,colors='blue',linewidths=1.)
plt.clabel(cs2, fontsize=9, inline=1) 
plt.savefig('sh-omega.png')
plt.show()
```

after upgrade pip and Libraries used , I got an error:property of 'QuadContourSet' object has no setter.
I would be grateful if someone could help me to fix this error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a code example we can run to reproduce the problem and/or provide the full traceback of the error so we can see where it is triggered (ideally both).  It is difficult to help otherwise.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Basemap has reached end of life](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/intro.html#cartopy-new-management-and-eol-announcement). This means that, if something changed its interfaces, no one will patch Basemap to comply.

Comment: @gboffi basemap is still going because a new maintainer stepped in.  However, it does not have much resource so progress is slow, including to remove the EOL notice https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/527

Comment: Basemap does not yet support Matplotlib v3.8 https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/594.  This could well be the problem since Matplotlib's `ContourSet` had substantial changes at v3.8.

Comment: @RuthC A new maintainer for Basemap is good news, but they really should update the text at the link rather than simply make a new announcement.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that I can reproduce? As others said, `basemap` is still not updated to support `matplotlib` 3.8, but a minimal reproducible example would be very useful for me to upgrade `basemap` accordingly.

Comment: Could the OP post, at least, the full back trace?

Comment: I have reproduced the error with examples from the basemap docs and left a comment over at https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/594

Comment: @gboffi The deprecation notice was removed from the docs months ago, but there was an issue with the upload process that could not be resolved until very recently. I have just uploaded the latest docs to https://matplotlib.org/basemap, so I hope that the confusion with the deprecation does not occur in the future. This was a triage decision: being the only active maintainer, I gave priority to solve problematic bugs that were compromising the functionality of the library. Of course the docs still needed an update, but anybody visiting the GitHub repo would see movement for the last two years.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of the OP, `basemap` 1.3.9 had an upper pin for `matplotlib` set explicitly to `<3.8`. The issue that is reached here is caused by an interface change in `matplotlib` for which `basemap` was still not prepared.

`basemap` 1.4.0 has just been released today (2024-01-09) with the `matplotlib` pin upgraded to `<3.9` and with your problem fixed:

```
python -m pip install "basemap >= 1.4.0"
```

I would like to thank @RuthC for contributing with the solution in the corresponding GitHub repo.